# How to display ONLY featured posts of a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-post-type

Good morning,

I've created a custom post type - Products - and for that custom post type I have 
created a custom field - featured_product - using the Advanced Custom Field plugin.
When I created the custom field, I did it using the True/False field type.

I am trying to display ONLY those Products posts where the featured_product checkbox
is checked.

This is my current code:

```
<?php query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'post_type' => 'products',
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'paged' => $paged
)
); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if(get_field('featured_product')){ ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cpt">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('excerpt');
}
?> 
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<ul class="prod_detail">
<li><a href="<?php the_field('product_detail_page'); ?>">Learn More</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php the_field('purchase_link'); ?>">Place Order</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The problem is that it only returns one post - but I have 3 posts checked as being featured.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out :)

```
<?php query_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'post_type' => 'products',
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'meta_key' => 'featured_product', // the name of the custom field
'meta_compare' => '=', // the comparison (e.g. equals, does not equal, etc...)
'meta_value' => 1, // the value to which the custom field is compared. In my case, 'featured_product' was a true/false checkbox. If you had a custom field called 'color' and wanted to show only those blue items, then the meta_value would be 'blue'
'paged' => $paged
)
); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cpt">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('excerpt');
}
?> 
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<ul class="prod_detail">
<li><a href="<?php the_field('product_detail_page'); ?>" target="_blank">Learn More</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php the_field('purchase_link'); ?>" target="blank">Place Order</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```